# Android forceclose on gridview scroll down

Tags: android, android-gridview

i have a gridview with 4 columns and some rows and i retrieve some data from web service and load it correctly in gridview adapter,the gridview shows the data but when a start to scroll down after a little bit of scrolling it force closes and i dont have any idea whats the problem? here is what logcat logged:

```
dalvik.system.nativestart.main
```

Comment: you've posted a partial log of the exception . please show more . also , please show some of your code.

Comment: Please post a stacktrace and the corresponding code snippet.